# K-means algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

How can we implement K-means algorithm in  Matlab without using kmeans(X,k) syntax?

Actually the problem is not implementing the algorithm. please see the the image below:
[image]

I implemented the algorithm offered from most of sites e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kmeans

```
1. Give initial values to m1 .. mk
2. Assignment with closest mean
3. Update
```

I set 4 observations of X (200 samples) which I knew already that these 4 observations are from 1 cluster.
hence, according to algorithm, the above clustering of shown image is explainable while that's not true. I think 4 initial values shouldn't select randomly.

I also run some other source code such as http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/kMean/matlab_kMeans.htm. the same result deduced. you can download my observations from http://www.4shared.com/get/IfwUEUBD/Observation.html and see by yourself the result.

Comment: If you want to know the `kmeans` source code, enter `type kmeans.m` at the command prompt in MATLAB.

Comment: @Ata: the algorithm is simple and well described: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering . You should be able to implement it yourself as an exercise. You can ask for help if you are having problems with the code, but show you have made an effort...

Comment: @Ata: Kmeans algorithm is very sensitive to initialization, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657801/matlab-kmeans-does-not-always-converge-to-global-minima

Answer (score 3):

if you want to implement your own k-means or (for whatever reason) dont want to use the MATLAB k-means syntax then there are a couple of ways:

1. read the paper: "An Efficient k-Means Clustering Algorithm:
   Analysis and Implementation", also read some other resources and then write your own code.
2. search the internet until you find some other free implementation so that you can use it in your code.

you may like to see the following link:

http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/kMean/index.html

Answer (score 0):

By "without using kmeans(X,k) syntax" do you mean without specifying k, the number of clusters, in advance? This isn't possible as the algorithm relies on knowing the number of clusters ahead of time. If you really want to perform clustering without knowing the number of clusters in advance I'd look into another algorithm such as the [DBSCAN algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).

If you want a K-means algorithm already implemented with source code available, check out [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org) for a solid implementation. The syntax is exactly kmeans(X,k) though.

Comment: Both of k and X is specified. I want to know k-means source code. I checked VLFeat. as it seems, it's a library which is compatible with matlab. can I find the solution as a function m file?

Comment: VLFeat is actually C code linked into Matlab via .mex files, so there isn't really any matlab code to look at. You can look at the C code, though, to see what's going on...