# MATLAB: K Means clustering With varying centroids

Tags: matlab, k-means, voronoi

I'm created a code book based on k-means clustering algorithm.But the algorithm didn't converge to an optimal code book, each time, the cluster centroids are varying(because of random selection of initial seeds). There is an option in Matlab to give an initial matrix to K-Means.But how we can can select the initial code book from a large data set?  Is there any other way to get a unique code book using K-means?

Comment: I'm not sure but it;s possible that quasi-random numbers will give you more a more stable initialization than the typical pseudo-random number do?

Comment: The best way to do that is to search for constant properties in your data, and use them to generate the initial codebook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB kMeans does not always converge to global minima](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657801/matlab-kmeans-does-not-always-converge-to-global-minima)

Comment: @Amro: yes.. each time,Matlab Kmeans give different codebook.

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat standard to run k-means multiple times using different initial states (e.g., initial seeds) and choose the result with the lowest error as the best result.

It's also typical to seed k-means by randomly choosing k elements from your data set as the initial seeds.

Comment: i tried with random seed, but my final codebook is not constant it changing. i think final codebook is depend on initial seed.

Comment: Yes, k-means is subject to local minima, so it's easy to get different final results from different seeds. To combat this, you should run it many times with different seeds and select the result with the lowest error.

Answer (score 1):

Since by default MATLAB's K-Means uses the K-MEans++ algorithm for initialization it means it uses random numbers.

Hence each call (For sequential calls) to K-Means will probably produce different results.

You have 3 options to make this deterministic:

1. Set MATLAB's Random Number Generator state to certain state before calling K-Means.
2. Use the stream option in K-Means options to set the stream inside K-Means.
3. Write your own version of K-Means which uses a deterministic way to initialize K-Means.